# Bootstrap Multi Level Menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navigationbar

trying to do a couple of things here but I cant seem to find how to make the following happen.

1. Make navigation menu drop down when hovered
2. Make sub menu appear on the right side of the parent item.

It seems as though all my menu items appear at the top like they are in a fixed position at the top of the navigation menu.

Im currently using Bootstrap 2.3.2

ANy ideas greatly appreciated, as I cant seem to find a snippet or real working example anywhere online

```
 <div class="nav-collapse collapse in hover">
        <ul class="nav">         
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="badge badge-success pull-left">100</span>&nbsp;Users  <b class="caret"></b></a>          
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="index.html">View Existing Users</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="">Add New User</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="layout.html">Roles & Groups</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="">Add New Role / Group</a></li>
                </ul>              
              </li>
              <li><a href="typography.html">Statistics</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!--- end user management --->
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Content <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="index.html">Site Navigation</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="">Add New Navigation Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Arrange Navigation Order</a></li>
                </ul>

              </li>
              <li><a href="layout.html">Pages</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="">Add New Page</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">SEO Utilities</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="layout.html">Gallery</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="">Add New Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">SEO Utilities</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="layout.html">Articles</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="">Add New Article</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">SEO Utilities</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>     
                <li><a href="layout.html">Code Snippets</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="">Add New Snippet</a></li>                 
                </ul>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Assets <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="layout.html">File Manager</a></li>
              <li><a href="layout.html">File Import</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="badge badge-success pull-left">100</span>&nbsp;Shop <b class="caret"></b></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="layout.html">Departments</a></li>
              <li><a href="layout.html">Products</a></li>
              <li><a href="layout.html">Discounts</a></li>
              <li><a href="layout.html">Orders<span class="badge badge-success pull-right">100</span>&nbsp;</a></li>
              <li><a href="layout.html">Settings</a></li>
              <li><a href="layout.html">Send to a Friend</a></li>
              <li><a href="layout.html">Reports</a></li>
              <li><a href="layout.html">Data Import</a></li>
              <li><a href="layout.html">Data Export</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>



          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Marketing <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="index.html">Facebook Insights</a></li>
              <li><a href="layout.html">Mail Chimp Login</a></li>
              <li><a href="typography.html">Typography</a></li>
              <li><a href="ui.html">Search Engine Utilities</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>


          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Settings <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="index.html">Website Settings</a></li>
              <li><a href="layout.html">Template Manager</a></li>
              <li><a href="layout.html">CSS Editor</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>


          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Statistics <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="index.html">Website Statistics</a></li>
              <li><a href="layout.html">Google Analytics</a></li>             
            </ul>
          </li>


        </ul>
        <div class="user-info pull-right">
          <div class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><img src="img/styler/dummy/daenerys.jpg"> Me <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="gallery.html">Your Profile <span class="badge badge-important pull-right">1</span></a></li>             
              <li><a href="stream.html">Account Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="stream.html">Messages</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <form class="form-search pull-right">
          <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Search anything here">
          <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!--- end navigation menu --->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<style>
/* MULTI-LEVEL DROPDOWNS FOR BOOTSTRAP */

.dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

.dropdown-menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    left
}

.navbar .sub-menu:before {
    border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-top: 7px solid transparent;
    left: -7px;
    top: 10px;
}
.navbar .sub-menu:after {
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 6px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    left: 10px;
    top: 11px;
    left: -6px;
}

        </style>
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try the code below:

```
.open .dropdown-toggle,.dropdown.open .dropdown-toggle{color: #666;} .open .dropdown-menu,.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu{display:none;}

.open > .dropdown-menu,.dropdown.open > .dropdown-menu{display:block;}

.open .dropdown-menu > .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu, .dropdown.open .dropdown-menu > .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu{ display:block; }

.dropdown-menu > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu { top: 0px; }

.dropdown-menu > .dropdown > .dropdown-toggle:hover { color:#fff; background-color: #0088cc; }

.dropdown-menu > .dropdown > .dropdown-toggle { background: none; }

.dropdown-menu > .dropdown.offset-left > .dropdown-menu { left: -100%; }

.dropdown-menu > .dropdown.offset-right > .dropdown-menu { left: 100%; }

.dropdown-menu > .dropdown.offset-left > .dropdown-menu:before, .dropdown-menu > 

.dropdown.offset-right > .dropdown-menu:before, .dropdown-menu > .dropdown.offset-left > 

.dropdown-menu:after, .dropdown-menu > .dropdown.offset-right > .dropdown-menu:after { content: ''; display: inline-block; border: 0; position: absolute; }
```

Comment: Please add code in proper format you will get from the tool box.
and please describe the code in few lines